# SignalR and PHP client using PHP's standard socket functions

Tags: php, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Does someone know a good example or tutorial or PHP socketclient (using PHP's socket functions) to wait for updates from SignalR server? I would like to connect to socket.bittrex.com to receive updates.

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");

$result = socket_connect($socket, gethostbyname('socket.bittrex.com'), 80) or die("Could not connect toserver\n");

echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
```

This echos Success but after that i am completely stuck what to do. I want my client to subscribe to some of the signalr subscriptions and wait for updates to be sent to the client and notice updates and do something with it.

Regards,

Marcel